# Nested documents and _id indexes in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with nested documents in it. Each document also has an _id field.

Here's an example of a documents structure

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("top_level_doc"),
   "title": "Cadernos",
   "parent": "4fd55bbc5d1709793b000008",
   "criterias": {
     "0": {
       "_id": ObjectId("a_nested_doc"),
       "value": "caderno",
       "operator": "contains",
       "field": "design0" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I want to be able to find the nested document just by searching it's _id

With this query

```
{
    "criterias._id" : ObjectId("a_nested_doc")
}
```

It returns the parent document (i just want the one that's nested).

Ideally I would do this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("a_nested_doc")
}
```

And it would return the document with that id (either its nested or not).

Ps. I edited the "_id" values for the sake of simplicity just for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to live with selecting criterias._id (without writing a wrapper around the query, at least), but you can select the document itself by simply retrieving a subset of the fields.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

```
// The simplest case converted to your use case
db.collection.find( { criterias._id : ObjectId("a_nested_doc") }, { criterias : 1 } );
```

Comment: I was hopping it didn't come to that since these documents are generated dynamicly and dont always hold the same structure (e.g. the field "criterias" could have a completly different name).

Comment: Can you please clarify in your question how two documents may differ (with an example if possible) with respect to this?

Comment: Well, the name of the field with the nested documents won't be always "criterias" but I will be always using the same code to query the database.

Comment: Anyway, I don't see any better alternative to using the method you described, so I will make changes to my code to make it work this way. Thank you

Comment: Scrapped my attempt at a comment, you're welcome and good luck.